# How to create network by GTFS data in ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, general-transit-feed-specification

I want to create my network by using a GTFS file. I already opened a network dataset but when I load the GFTS to network dataset tool it gives me some errors.

Can someone please help? Below is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more details on your process; furthermore, where are you getting the GTFS data from? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: this is odd. I use the same analyst extension, my GTFS file doesn't have the wheelchair_boarding column, and it's never complained -- I would try adding the column with 0's as per user1886721's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

That error suggests your GTFS data is missing the (optional per spec IIRC) wheelchair_boarding column. Maybe try adding this column in using Excel / LibreOffice?

If that doesn't help, there is a line number in the Python file that should get closer to the issue.